# AngularJS how to pass event from ng-really click

Tags: html, angularjs, coffeescript

I want to pass event to my method but it arrives like 'undefined'. Here is my attitude

```
  <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-really-message="Are you sure want to delete?"
         ng-really-click="uc.deleteUser(user.id)">
         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> </button>
```

My method in .coffee file

```
    deleteProduct: (id, event) ->
       console.log(event)
       @ProductService.deleteProduct(id)
       .then(
           (data) =>
               @getAllProducts()
           ,
           (error) =>
               @$log.error "Unable to delete Products: #{error}"
           )
```

However if i pass event by ng-click it works fine. According to '*ng-really click*' $event diasappears imagically!!! Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a version that supports passing `$event`:

```
app.directive('ngReallyClick', ['$parse',
  function($parse) {
    return {
      compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
        var fn = $parse(tAttrs.ngReallyClick);
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
          element.on('click', function(event) {
            var message = attrs.ngReallyMessage;
            if (message && confirm(message)) {
              scope.$apply(function() {
                fn(scope, {
                  $event: event
                });
              });
            }
          });
        };
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Usage:

```
ng-really-click="uc.deleteUser(user.id, $event)"
```